# No coffee, no workee - meaning

Tags: meaning, rhymes

> **no coffee, no workee**

What exactly does this expression mean? And how do you pronounce it?

Comment: It's just a jocular catchphrase sometimes printed on the "personalised coffee mugs" people keep in the office. All it means is *"If this cup isn't regularly filled with coffee, I will not work"*. Personally I think it's potentially offensive to people from the Far East, so I wouldn't promote it.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers inferred, it's potentially offensive to people from the Far East.  That's because it is a take-off on an expression that had been used to sound like someone at a Chinese laundry..."no tickee, no washee!", which meant that without a ticket, you could not pick up your laundry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, because it's an exact replacement in meaning..."no (incentive), no (reward)".  Your 2nd example is just another example of a stereotype of an Asian (prostitute in that case).  They're only alike in that they're stereotypes.  (You're so naughty!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a Westerner I find "love you long time" offensive. I believe the standard is "short time" and I would hate to have to suffer attempts at upselling because of my race.

Comment: @Kristina: I know that one was a bit ott. I was just thinking that maybe if anyone *was* bothered by it, this might prompt them to consider the possibility of *others* being bothered by the "Chinese pidgin" stereotype. I've never actually been to the Far East, and most of the Asians I meet are at pains to acquire fluency in English as quickly as possible. So my main exposure to the stereotype is from *Westerners* (often, poking fun at supposedly illiterate foreigners). Maybe I should have cited *"No workee no payee"* from a typical ignorant colonial.

Comment: @FumbleFingers..."typical ignorant colonial" meaning one of us Yanks?

Comment: I'm hoping it is a legit slogan for people everywhere to demand reg coffee breaks. Generally 10-15 minutes. You can use this time to eat or meditate. Taking a coffee  at work needs to be a right.

Comment: An enlightened boss employs has-beans.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It ***may be*** a take-off on an expression that had been used to sound like someone at a Chinese laundry...***"no tickee, no washee!"***, which meant that without a ticket, you could not pick up your laundry.  So ***"no coffee, no workee"*** means that without the coffee, you'll get no work.

This original expression that mimics Chinese Pidgin English, spoken by early Chinese immigrants, gained further notoriety after a 1921 silent movie was released, entitled, "[No Tickee, No Shirtee](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0403355/)".

Comment: Regardless of the origin, I don't think current usage is intended to refer to any old stereotype, any more than *No shirt, no shoes, no service* or *No jaw-jaw, only war-war* is. I would not ascribe racist motivations to the producer or owner of the mug.

Comment: @choster I agree, I had never heard of 'no tickee no washee', hence my answer. I didn't realise it was so complicated!

Comment: @choster, that would probably be true and may not be intended to offend, but you can't deny that there is no need to make "work" into "workee" if you're not intending a particular meaning.  It wouldn't make sense on its own.  If that were the case, why not just say, "No coffee, no work"?

Comment: @Mynamite, that's because you're probably not as *old* or from the same part of the world as me. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez *No coffee, no workee* is childlike. It's cute. It's playful. It's exactly the kind of thing I'd put on a coffee mug. *No coffee, no work* is rather prosaic, and even a little confrontational. It's whine-whine without rhyme-rhyme.

Comment: @choster, you can attribute child-like qualities to the saying if you want but I don't know many children that speak Chinese Pidgin English.  Try looking it up instead of just arguing about it. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I accept that your answer is correct but I agree with choster again - it's a play on words like so many others, eg JM Barrie is credited with inventing the name Wendy from ['friendy-wendy'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendy_Darling#The_name_Wendy)

Comment: @Mynamite.  I totally agree also that it's a play on words - and it stands on its own now.  I was only trying to make the point that it didn't appear out of a vacuum.  It has a history that fortunately is not popular any longer.

Comment: @KristinaLopez  I don't know if you're familiar with the British pantomime Aladdin, set partly in a Chinese laundry. Aladdin's mother is [Widow Twankey (Tuang kee)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow_Twankey) and his brother Wishee-washee. Not very politically correct, but the characters are much loved.

Comment: @Mynamite, Oh boy, that's fraught with PC no-no's! lol!  Here in the US, we had a laundry soap (or water softener?) TV ad in the 70's that had stereotypical Chinese laundry workers use their Chinese Pidgin English to hawk the product..."Ancient Chinese Secret!": http://youtu.be/BJP5f-fsHrs

Comment: @KristinaLopez: "No coffee, no workee" has a nice rhyme, lyrical cadence, a child-like tone, and is non-threatening. "No coffee, no work" is harsher, abrasive even. The first feels like a joke about how important coffee is, while the second seems like a threat of work stoppage.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: I agree 100% with your answer, but I have to say, having seen those commercials air "first-run" that is decidedly NOT "Pidgin English" they are speaking. The laundry and the slogan are problematic, but the actors are straight-up American.

Comment: I, too, had never heard of the Chinese pidgin examples, and I don't think it necessary to read that into things in this case. The -ee on "workee" is simply a playful way to make "work" rhyme with "coffee". It could have, and in many cases probably *did*, "appear out of a vacuum", because it's simply copying the last two letters of one word and tacking them on to the other. (Surely you're not arguing that "no [x], no [y]" is not a native English construct?)

Comment: @Marthaª, opinions without citation are usually not acceptable here.  Do you have anything more concrete to refute that it's more than coincidence that "no coffee, no workee" has parallel meaning and odd wording than my answer?  Please share! :-)

Comment: @horatio, you're right about the actors, but their dialog is meant to sound a little like the pidgin English, I think.  It's kind of a thing here in the US that the commercial is very un-PC nowadays.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: surely you don't need a citation to prove that "workee" and "coffee" have the same ending? That the last two letters of "coffee" have been tacked onto the word "work"? That the resulting expression is fully natural English, apart from the non-word "workee"? That if I have never heard of "no tickee no washee", it cannot possibly be anything other than coincidence that it sounds very similar to the playful rhyme I just made up?

Answer (score 6):

"-ie" or "-y"  is sometimes used as a suffix to denote childish speech.  In this case the same sound has been written as "-ee" in order to match the ending of "coffee".

So it just means "Without coffee I can't work." But expressed in a childish way to imply reduced ability to think due to lack of caffeine.

Comment: I would have taken it as baby talk as well smithkm.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: you keep repeating that as if it were irrefutable truth, but the fact that smithkm, Motes, and many other people (including me) just thought it was simple playful rhyming **proves** that it can and does arise as, well, simple playful rhyming.

Comment: @Marthaª, comments aside, which I already explained how they came to be, since this site is supposed to be for supported answers, you can't argue with the fact that mine does have historical precedence.  The fact that others see it is as playful rhyming, though not untrue, is without any cited source.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: why on earth would I need to cite a source for my *experience*? And the very fact that I was able to have that experience disproves your assertion. You're saying that "x always derives from y", while I'm saying that "I came up with x, and I've never heard of y, so obviously x does ***not*** always derive from y".

Comment: @Marthaª, unless you designed the coffee cup with that saying, you didn't "come up" with that expression.  This is a question and answer site.  I answered a question with some historical background suggesting that it is the source of the OP's referenced expression.  You're perfectly welcome to like it or not - and if not, to provide cited evidence of another source of that expression. :-)

Comment: @Kristina, I ***have*** provided cited evidence of another source of that expression: it rhymes. It sounds cutesy. QED. Or to put it another way: you didn't design that cup either, so you can't know what was going through the design person's head. Your interpretation is no more likely than mine, yours is just, well, meaner. Less PC. Ascribing malice where ignorance would suffice.

Comment: @Marthaª, it's not just the turning of "work" into "workee".  It's the *meaning* of the expression that parallels the meaning of "no tickee, no washee".  And as far as "meaner" goes, I didn't invent the original expression, I'm only citing it as I said, a historical reference.  If it offends you, I'm very sorry.  What I can't understand, ultimately, is *your* hostility.  May I suggest **de-caffee**? lol!  Just kidding!  You can't take anything too seriously here! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a play on words. Coffee is usually pronounced 'coffy' but here, to emphasis the play, both words would have the 'ee' ending as in 'feet'.

Used by those who cannot function without their coffee, it means:

> Give me a cup of coffee or I'm not going to work for you

Or, more politely

> I'm just going to  make myself a cup of coffee and then I'll be happy
>   to do some work

Comment: Mynamite, what exactly is the pronunciation difference between "coffy" and "coffee"? Do you really pronounce "coffee" on its own differently than the "coffee" in "no workee no coffee"? Personally, I don't see how that's possible...

Comment: @Marthaª I tried to describe it in my 1st sentence but maybe I didn't explain it well. I pronounce coffee with a short final 'i' sound, like fluffy or puffy. But with 'no coffee no workee' I would emphasise the final long -ee. I can't explain why, I just would - because it's playful and there's no such word as 'worky/workee'

Answer (score 2):

It means one cannot concentrate on work without having coffee.

Comment: That is a possible interpretation, but it can also suggest *I refuse to even attempt to work unless I have coffee*.

Comment: Yes that can also be a point but when you look at reality it is hyperbole. One cannot concentrate on work but nobody quits or don't work all all without coffee.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Chris Farleyian way to say "I cannot work (function) without coffee."  I would pronounce it using [this voice](http://www.hulu.com/watch/4183).